# Android Software Keyboard triggers quick search bar

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am having this weird problem. I have an EditText like this:

```
<EditText 
        android:id="@+id/wordTxt"   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/enter_word"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"        
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="text"        
        android:imeOptions="normal"/>
```

The problem is that sometimes when the EditText get a focus, the soft keyboard being displayed is the keyboard that trigger the Android Quick Launch Bar, not the keyboard to fill the EditText. It happens especially after phone reboot. I've searched the internet but couldn't find any solution. Anyone have solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know the cause of this problem, but after an investigation I've concluded that it happens when I send a Text-To-Speech Intent in `onCreate` method. If I skip this step, the problem was disappear. As a solution, I create the Intent in a different Thread that will be started after some milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this can help, Just try this

```
InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```